# Add unknown number of elements to another cell array from a certain index on

Tags: matlab, cell-array, insertion

I've data in the format of

```
a{1}(1,1)=1
a{1}(1,2)=3
a{1}(1,3)=0.5 
a{1}(2,1)=1
a{1}(2,2)=5
a{1}(3,1)=2
a{1}(3,2)=7

 ...
```

Now I'd like to place item 1 & 2 of all rows in this cell into another cell array from an specific index on. How should I do this? for example to place column 1 & 2 of these unknown number of row in the cell array 'b' from index 5 on without repetition I used:

```
 b{1}(1,(5:end + 1)) = unique(a{1}(:,(1:2)))
```

I'd like the output of cell array 'b{1}' from 5th elements becomes   '1 2 3 5 7'. 
However, it is false and gives the "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." error. I dont know where is the problem. Is my snippet right? 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please give an example of your wanted output

Comment: Your code will only work if the number of unique elements in the first two collumns of `a{1}` is the same as `size(b{1},2)-3`. I'm guessing this is not the case with your data. Instead you could do something like: `list = unique(a{1}(:,1:2)); b{1}(1,5:(numel(list)+4)) = list;`

Comment: That's an exact guess and solution. In fact, i thought my solution did not work when in some iteration I had repetitive inclusion (e.g. [1 2 3] in one run and new run again [1 2 3]; so the index end+1 made the error. So I used size function to count number of both array (a , also b from index 5 on). if they were not equal my code works and otherwise not, So I used an if to resolve the problem. But your code is much smarter and works excellent! Thanks:)